# Validação de formulário de email com javascript

Tags: javascript, email, validação

Criei um formulário para envio de email, consigo enviar o e-mail mas não consigo verificar se os campos estão preenchidos.

```js
 
<script type="text/javascript">
function checkEmail () {
 var name = document.form.name;
 var email = document.form.email;
 var subject = document.form.subject;
 var message = document.form.message;
 var count = 0;
 var flagError = false;
 var error="";
 
 if (name == "") {
  error += "O campo Nome deve ser preenchido.";
  count = count + 1
  flagError = true;
 }
 
 if (email == "") {
  error += "O endereço de e-mail deve ser preenchido.";
  count = count + 1
  flagError = true;
 }
 
 if (subject == "") {
  error += "O campo Assunto deve ser preenchido.";
  count = count + 1
  flagError = true;
 }
 
 if (message == "") {
  error += "O campo Mensagem deve ser preenchido.";
  count = count + 1
  flagError = true;
 }
 
 if (count > 0 )
          alert("Os seguintes erros foram encontrados:\n" + erro);
 
 if (!flagError) {
  var illegalChars = /(@.*@)|(@\.)|(@\-)|(@_)(\.@)|(\-@)|(\.\.)|(^\.)|(\.$)|(\.\-)|(\._)|(\-\.)|(_\.)|(^_)|(_$)|(_\-)|(\-\-)|(^\-)|(\-$)|(\-_)/;
  if (email.match(illegalChars)) {
   error += "O endereço de e-mail contém caracteres inválidos.";
   count = count + 1
   flagError = true;
  }
 }

 if (!flagError) {
  var emailFilter = /^\S+\@(\[?)[a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+\.([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$/;
  if (!(emailFilter.test(email))) { 
   error += "O endereço de e-mail não está em um formato válido.";
   count = count + 1
   flagError = true;
  }
 }

 if (!flagError) {
  var emailFilter = /^([a-zA-Z0-9\@_\-\.\+]+)$/;
  if (!(emailFilter.test(email))) { 
   error += "O endereço de e-mail não está em um formato válido.";
   count = count + 1
   flagError = true;
  }
 }
 if (!flagError) {
  flagError = false;
  window.alert("Mensagem enviada com sucesso!")
  }

 if (flagError) {
  window.alert(error);
 }

 return !flagError;
}
</script>
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Contato</title>
</head>

<body>

<p>Envie sua mensagem:</p>
    
    
<form method="post" action="http://www18.locaweb.com.br/scripts/FormMail.pl"/>


    
      <p><input type="text" placeholder="Nome" required name="name" id="name"></p>
      <p><input type="text" placeholder="Email" required name="email" id="email"></p>
      <p><input type="text" placeholder="Assunto" required name="subject" id="subject"></p>
      <p><input type="text" placeholder="Mensagem" required name="message" id="message"></p>
      <p>
        <button type="submit" name="Submit" onclick="javascript: var submit = checkEmail(getElementById('id').value); return submit;"> ENVIAR MENSAGEM </button>
      </p>
    </form>
    
    
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: O que quer dizer com "*não verifica os campos*"?

Comment: Não verifica se os campos foram preenchidos e não verifica se o email está correto, e estando tudo certo, não aparece a mensagem final de email enviado com sucesso.

Comment: M. Nunes, conseguiu resolver?

Comment: Sim, consegui resolver, segui a orientação do Icaro Martins, funcionou perfeitamente.

Answer (score 3):

Olhei seu código mudei a forma como você esta tentando fazer o `submit` e corrigi alguns problemas e coloquei alguns comentários para explicar o que fiz, espero que te ajude. =D

```js
function checkEmail () {
        var frm = document.forms[0];
///                           ^ faltava o `s`, alem de ser uma array   
     var name = frm.name.value;
///                     ^ name == `HTMLElement` pelo codigo parece que você quer o `value`
     var email = frm.email.value;
     var subject = frm.subject.value;
     var message = frm.message.value;
     var count = 0;
     var flagError = false;
     var error="";
     
     if (name == "") {
      error += "O campo Nome deve ser preenchido.";
      count = count + 1
      flagError = true;
     }
     
     if (email == "") {
      error += "O endereço de e-mail deve ser preenchido.";
      count = count + 1
      flagError = true;
     }
     
     if (subject == "") {
      error += "O campo Assunto deve ser preenchido.";
      count = count + 1
      flagError = true;
     }
     
     if (message == "") {
      error += "O campo Mensagem deve ser preenchido.";
      count = count + 1
      flagError = true;
     }
     
     if (count > 0 ){
              alert("Os seguintes erros foram encontrados:\n" + error);
///              a variável usada esta com o nome errado `erro`   ^
              return;
///             ^  estava aparecendo dois alerts entao coloquei um return aqui
        
     }

     if (!flagError) {
      var illegalChars = /(@.*@)|(@\.)|(@\-)|(@_)(\.@)|(\-@)|(\.\.)|(^\.)|(\.$)|(\.\-)|(\._)|(\-\.)|(_\.)|(^_)|(_$)|(_\-)|(\-\-)|(^\-)|(\-$)|(\-_)/;
      if (email.match(illegalChars)) {
       error += "O endereço de e-mail contém caracteres inválidos.";
       count = count + 1
       flagError = true;
      }
     }

     if (!flagError) {
      var emailFilter = /^\S+\@(\[?)[a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+\.([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$/;
      if (!(emailFilter.test(email))) { 
       error += "O endereço de e-mail não está em um formato válido.";
       count = count + 1
       flagError = true;
      }
     }

     if (!flagError) {
      var emailFilter = /^([a-zA-Z0-9\@_\-\.\+]+)$/;
      if (!(emailFilter.test(email))) { 
       error += "O endereço de e-mail não está em um formato válido.";
       count = count + 1
       flagError = true;
      }
     }
     if (!flagError) {
      flagError = false;
            frm.submit()
///              ^ fazer o submit do form se tudo estiver correto 
      window.alert("Mensagem enviada com sucesso!")
      }

     if (flagError) {
      window.alert(error);
     }

     return !flagError;
    }
```

```html
    <!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Contato</title>
    </head>

    <body>

    <p>Envie sua mensagem:</p>
        
        
    <form method="post" action="http://www18.locaweb.com.br/scripts/FormMail.pl"/>


        
          <p><input type="text" placeholder="Nome" required name="name" id="name"></p>
          <p><input type="text" placeholder="Email" required name="email" id="email"></p>
          <p><input type="text" placeholder="Assunto" required name="subject" id="subject"></p>
          <p><input type="text" placeholder="Mensagem" required name="message" id="message"></p>
          <p>
            <button type="button" onclick="checkEmail()"> ENVIAR MENSAGEM </button>
          </p>
        </form>
        
        
        
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Perfeito, totalmente funcional.

Comment: Agradeço a ajuda

Answer (score 2):

Analisando seu código, encontrei dois problemas que estão impedindo o funcionamento de seu código.

1. A forma como você captura o valor dos elementos inclusos no seu `formulário`.
2. A variável `erro` no trecho: `alert("Os seguintes erros foram encontrados:\n" + erro);` não existe.

**Solução¹**: A propriedade `form` no trecho `document.form` não existe, acredito que você tentou acessar o `HTMLCollection` pela propriedade [`forms`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/forms).
Note que a propriedade `forms` retorna uma Coleção de objetos *HTML* de acordo com a quantidade de formulários inclusos em seu código fonte, então para solucionar seu problema você vai acessar o atributo da seguinte forma: `document.forms[índice]`, como só existe um formulário, vamos utilizar o índice `0`(*já que só existe um formulário*). Ao acessar o formulário, os campos também são retornados em uma lista de `inputs`. Como você possui 4 campos, vamos acessá-los da seguinte maneira: `document.forms[índice].[índice_do_elemento];`. Observe a seguinte imagem para facilitar o entendimento.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ou seja, para acessar os itens, você vai substituir seu código:

```
var name = document.form.name;
var email = document.form.email;
var subject = document.form.subject;
var message = document.form.message;
```

por:

```
var name = document.forms[0][0].value; //name
var email = document.forms[0][1].value; //email
var subject = document.forms[0][2].value; //subject
var message = document.forms[0][3].value; //message
```

**Solução²**: Basta alterar a variável `erro`, para `error`. Uma vez que a variável `erro` não existe.

**Nota**: Existem [várias maneiras para acessar os elementos de seu formulário](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/coll_form_elements.asp), a forma que utilizei para solucionar seu problema foi apenas para manter sua sintaxe.